# While loop running incorrect number of times

Tags: java, random, while-loop, boolean

I am having trouble with a `while-loop`, as the if statement is meant to check if the button is empty if not repeat. However if the whole if statement is in a `while-loop` it reveals about 4 buttons after running the code for the first time.

```
case HINT:
    Random random = new Random();
    int size = SizeOfPuzzle.currentRows;
    int randomNumber1 = random.nextInt(size);
    int randomNumber2 = random.nextInt(size);
    if (puzzlePanel.arrayOfButtons[randomNumber1][randomNumber2].getText().isEmpty()) {
       puzzlePanel.arrayOfButtons[randomNumber1][randomNumber2].setText(puzzle.getSingleLetter(randomNumber1, randomNumber2) + "");
    }else {
       boolean finished = true;
       while (!finished) {
          randomNumber1 = random.nextInt(size);
          randomNumber2 = random.nextInt(size);
          if (puzzlePanel.arrayOfButtons[randomNumber1][randomNumber2].getText().isEmpty()) {
              puzzlePanel.arrayOfButtons[randomNumber1][randomNumber2].setText(puzzle.getSingleLetter(randomNumber1, randomNumber2) + "");
              break;
          }

       }
    }
break;
```

Comment: And what is you question or problem? You need to add clarity to you post.

Comment: One line before `while (!finished)` you set `finished` to be `true`, the condition won't be evaluated to `true` since `!true` is `false`.

Comment: Please read: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @BrettWalker To clarify How am I to rectify my problem as the loop does not seem to run. At some points it does not repeat to find a clear button in the array without clicking the menu option several times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must initialize `finished` to `false` if you want to enter the while, and after, when job is done set `finished` to `true` to exit the loop

```
boolean finished = false;
while (!finished) {
//     ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ →→→→→→ this means loop while finished == false 
    randomNumber1 = random.nextInt(size);
    randomNumber2 = random.nextInt(size);
    if (puzzlePanel.arrayOfButtons[randomNumber1][randomNumber2].getText().isEmpty()) {
        puzzlePanel.arrayOfButtons[randomNumber1][randomNumber2].setText(puzzle.getSingleLetter(randomNumber1, randomNumber2) + "");
        finished = true;
     }    
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Identified the main problem was the finished = true; right after the while loop began. Silly little mistake.